# Main list also getting updated with the copied one

Tags: python, list

I want to keep the `newlist` as is all the time, but want to update `newlistcopy` each time the loop condition is True. But I can see that `newlist` and `newlistcopy` both are getting updated even though I just updated the value of `newlistcopy`, not `newlist`:

```
a=[968, 566, 536, 98, 9, 5]
newlist=[0,3,4,6]
newlistcopy= newlist
newlist_=[]

for i in range(len(newlistcopy)-1):
    for j in range(len(newlistcopy)-1):
        if newlist[j+1]-newlistcopy[j]>=1: 
            newlist_.append(a[newlistcopy[j]])
            newlistcopy[j]+=1
```

Comment: The fallacy is in the third line.

Comment: You **never, ever** copy any list in your code.

Comment: Yes, newlist.copy() worked for me, thanks